# How to access data members of a class that have the same name in the constructor by the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Here is my code :

```
class Botato:
    sweety = 0

    def __init__(self, sw):
        self.sweety = sw


obj = Botato(5) 
print(obj.sweety)

output : 5
```

I want to print out the value of the class variable ***sweety*** by the object itself.

Comment: `print(Botato.sweety)`

Comment: You are *shadowing* the class variable with an instance variable. It is not accessible through the instance, but you can always access it directly on the class.